# SED: multiple patterns in a line and print next word

Tags: regex, sed

I have the result of a post and I want to print the back word of all occurrences with "mod=" and if possible separate them with a ,

Example:

> var1=prueba1&mod=SgaCac&mod=SgaGenSgm&env=&var2=prueba2

should print

> SgaCac,SgaGenSgm

I have tried with

```
echo "var1=prueba1&mod=SgaCac&mod=SgaGenSgm&env=&var2=prueba2" | sed 's/^.*mod=\([^&]*\).*/\1/'
```

but only print me one occurrence

> SgaGenSgm

Comment: See https://ideone.com/COy7Vc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
$ s="var1=prueba1&mod=SgaCac&mod=SgaGenSgm&env=&var2=prueba2"

$ awk -F'=' -v RS='&' -v OFS=',' '/^mod/{v=(v ? v OFS:"")$2}END{print v}' <<<"$s"
SgaCac,SgaGenSgm
```

**Explanation:**

- `-F='='` Field/column separator being set to `=`
- `-v RS='&'` Record/row separator as `&`, so that it will override, default row separator newline char (`\n`), so `awk` will interpret `&` as end of line.
- `-v OFS=','` Output Field Separator as comma
- `/^mod/` if line starts with regex, then
- `v=(v ? v OFS:"")$2` concatenate variable `v` with existing content if exists, and second field (`$2`) where separator being comma, other just second field
- `END{print v}` at the end print variable `v` contents

Answer (score 0):

GNU **awk** solution:

```
s="var1=prueba1&mod=SgaCac&mod=SgaGenSgm&env=&var2=prueba2"
awk -v FPAT="mod=[^=&]+" '{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s%s",substr($i,5),(i<NF)?",":ORS }' <<<"$s"
```

The output:

```
SgaCac,SgaGenSgm
```

Answer (score 0):

with sed

```
sed -E 's/.*&mod=([^&]*)&mod=([^&]*).*/\1,\2/'
```

With awk

```
awk -F"=|&" '{print $4","$6}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Following awk may help you in same(tested with provided ).

```
echo "var1=prueba1&mod=SgaCac&mod=SgaGenSgm&env=&var2=prueba2" | awk -F"&" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i ~ /mod/){sub(/mod.*=/,"",$i);val=val?val "," $i:$i}};print val;val=""}'
```

Output will be as follows.

```
SgaCac,SgaGenSgm
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too here.

```
echo "var1=prueba1&mod=SgaCac&mod=SgaGenSgm&env=&var2=prueba2" |
awk -F"&" '{
for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
 if($i ~ /mod/){
   sub(/mod.*=/,"",$i);
   val=val?val "," $i:$i;
}
}
print val;
val="";
}'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -nr 'G;:a;s/mod=([^&\n]*)(.*)/\2,\1/;ta;s/.*\n,//p' file
```

Append a newline to the pattern space (PS) and using pattern matching move the required string(s) to the right of the newline. Remove all characters upto and including the newline and print the remainder.

N.B. This idiom has been slightly amended to use the `,` separator.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk -v RS='&' -F'=' '$1=="mod"{print $2}' file
SgaCac
SgaGenSgm

$ awk -v RS='&' -F'=' '$1=="mod"{o=o s $2; s=","} END{print o}' file
SgaCac,SgaGenSgm
```